# Struts2 and Struts2 JQuery Plugin compatibility

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, struts2

I'm using Struts2 and I want to do an ajax post to upload a file to the server side. I have installed Struts2 JQuery Plugin, but I think it's a compatibility problem, because when I load my page, the chrome console show this problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
jQuery.struts2_jquery.version="3.6.0"; Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'version' of undefined
```

I have tried other versions of plugin (3.3.0, 3.7.0), but I have the same problem. I'm using struts2-core-2.3.1.2.

My web.xml have:

```
<filter>
       <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>    
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And the header of my jsp is:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<title></title>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<sj:head jqueryui="true"/>
<tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
```

And my sj:submit to upload the file:

```
<s:url id="servicesUrl" action="ajaxCall"></s:url>
<sj:submit name="button1" value="Submit" href="%{servicesUrl}" targets="myAjaxTarget" ></sj:submit>
<div id="myAjaxTarget">
</div>
```

And under this part of the submit, chrome shows

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

PD: If I can complete the question, tell me and I'll do it with more information

Comment: `jquery.js` is also a `jquery`lib right.

Comment: Why are you adding `js/jquery.js` and `js/jquery-ui.js` to the page?? Remove this and any other random JavaScript imports that shouldn't be there. The **whole point** of the `head` tag is to import and configure the right version!

Answer (score 3):

While using this

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
```

No need of using

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Since `<sj:head/>` generates all the imports needed to run `jquery`.

Comment: I have removed the jquery.js sentence, but now I have the next error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
jquery.struts2.min.js?s2j=3.6.0

Comment: @borjaps have you removed **all** the script imports or just that one?

Comment: I have removed all the script import, and now I get other problems with jquery:
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.  - jquery-1.10.0.min.js:6 
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function